# GCP Kubernetes behaviour on System.exit(1)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

What is the default behaviour on GCP Kubernetes for Spring Boot applications when

> System.exit(1)

is called? Will kubernetes recreate the container?
If no - how can i force recreation if my application crashes?

-Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On exit code for application kubernetes will restart the container inside the POD and pod state will change to in `Ready` column.

if you want to terminate pod gracefully you can have a look at this : `https://dzone.com/articles/gracefully-shutting-down-java-in-containers`

```
Terminated: Indicates that the container completed its execution and has stopped running. A container enters into this when it has successfully completed execution or when it has failed for some reason. Regardless, a reason and exit code is displayed, as well as the container’s start and finish time. Before a container enters into Terminated, preStop hook (if any) is executed.

...
      State:          Terminated
        Reason:       Completed
        Exit Code:    0
        Started:      Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
        Finished:     Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
    ...
```

Please have a look at kubernetes official doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/